# UWP Adding The MySQL Connector error

Tags: c#, mysql, reference, uwp

Im Trying to reference The MySQL Connector TO My UWP Project and im getting this error:
[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qNCYu.png)

What Should i Do?

Answer (score -1):

The Reference DLL that you are using is not compatible with UWP. You need to download the Extension from [Here](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=SQLiteDevelopmentTeam.SQLiteforUniversalWindowsPlatform)

Full documentation and Detailed explanation of how to add a SQLite Database is mentioned in this document [here](https://blogs.windows.com/buildingapps/2017/02/06/using-sqlite-databases-uwp-apps/#GpifeybXLUuyfKuK.97)

Good Luck.